# using &#10(line feed) in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My tag :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="All customer Data" data-content="Name : Cornelius &nbsp &nbsp  Customer Number : 21212121">
  Show All
</button>
```

In this `&nbsp` seems to be working perfectly fine but I need `&#10` to work for line feed which I tried in all the browsers is not working.

Comment: Sorry, what is not working? Can you show some correct HTML (including all quotation marks) with the &#10; and tell us what you expect to happen? `data-` attributes don't do anything by themselves. Oh, and HTML treats a linefeed as a space in output, and if you want the button to have two lines in its content, you should use`<br>`, but I'm sure you knew.

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="All customer Data" data-content="Name : Cornelius &#10 &#10  Customer Number : 21212121">
  Show All
</button> is it your html ?

Comment: @KAG See Filype's answer.

Comment: right, but he also forgot to close data-content="

Comment: What I want to accomplish by using &#10; is to have a line break where ever I put it inside the "data-content" attribute's value. Using <br /> prints out "<br />" as it is but no luck with the line break.

Comment: Yes, KAG. where you wrote "&#10" I need a line break on the output screen.

Comment: Mr. Lister, I dont want a button to have two lines. All I need is a line break inside "data-content" attribute's value. A way to put something instead of &nbsp in my html to have a line break. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the semi-colon. Use `&#10;`

Comment: Which will accomplish nothing on screen

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I want to accomplish by using &#10; is to have a line break where ever I put it inside the "data-content" attribute's value. Using <br /> prints out "<br />" as it is but no luck with the line break.

Answer (score 1):

Although `&#10;` may be the line feet character, you have to remember that line breaks are ignored in HTML, unless in a `<pre>` statement.

```html
<p>This will &#10; be one line.</p>
<pre>This will &#10; be two lines.</pre>
```

The right way to do this is with the `<br />` tag. There's no reason to not use it too. It's 5 characters, just like the alternative, and you **should** use it because it's more readable.

Comment: What I want is to do a line break being inside the "data-content". When I use <br /> inside its value it prints out "<br />" as it is.

Comment: Where is that data-content used?